# ERD diagram doesn't show cases linked to Account so how is it happening?

Tags: developer

Refer to ERD - https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_support.htm

It shows that Cases are not linked to Accounts anyway. But on the pagelayout of cases we can link cases to a contact as well as a account!

Q1. How is this possible?
Q2. Why does SFDC allow assigning contact and unrelated account to a cases? What is the business case here?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to see following ERD http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm

In terms of Sales Cloud, it is mandatory to keep track of company (Account) and its representatives (Contact) so, Salesforce maintain a conditional relationship between Case, Account and Contact.

- When a Contact has lookup to Account they act as Master-Detail.
- When a Account is associated with Case. Account can not cannot be deleted. You have to first delete Case record.

These type of out of the box relationship Salesforce have.

Answer (score 0):

What Ashwani wrote is 100% correct. Just to add to that, Cases get their account from the related contact. Sometimes there are use cases were you want the asset to define the account and not the contact at which point you will need to use an apex trigger to switch the association around. Use case being a contact from another account (ABC Company) calls in a support issue for an asset related to a different account (XYZ Company).